# Psycopg3: How to use Identifier in executemany()

Tags: psycopg2, psycopg3

I'm trying in python to use psycopg (version 3.1.4) to truncate a lot of tables with executemany(), but can't figure out what to use as a placeholder in the query. The [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/cursors.html#psycopg.Cursor.executemany) doesn't really say anything on this as far as I can see.

My code looks like this:

```
# Make a list of list of Identifiers ('tables' is the list of tables)
vals = [[sql.Identifier(schemaname, t)] for t in tables] 

# Truncate all tables on the schema
query = sql.SQL("truncate table {};")
cursor.executemany(query=query, params_seq=vals)
```

This gives me the error: `psycopg.ProgrammingError: the query has 0 placeholders but 1 parameters were passed`

If I instead use `%s` as a placeholder I get: `psycopg.ProgrammingError: cannot adapt type 'Identifier' using placeholder '%PyFormat.AUTO' (format: AUTO)`

Which placeholder will make this work? Or do I need to build the params-seq differently?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing value parameters and dynamic SQL. Your attempt `cursor.executemany(query=query, params_seq=vals)` does not work because `vals` are not what `executemany` is expecting which is a list of values parameters. Where values are data values, either being passed into a table or used in filtering data. What you are trying to do is build dynamic SQL over a list of identifiers, that is a different problem.

A solution:

```
import psycopg
from psycopg import sql
from psycopg import ClientCursor

con = psycopg.connect("dbname=test host=localhost  user=postgres")
cur = ClientCursor(con)

tbl_list = ['tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3']

for tbl in tbl_list:
    trunc_sql = sql.SQL("truncate table {}").format(sql.Identifier(tbl))
    print(cur.mogrify(trunc_sql))

truncate table "tbl1"
truncate table "tbl2"
truncate table "tbl3"
```

I used `ClientCursor` instead of `con.cursor()` in order to get the `mogrify` method and use it to display the built query.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, but this does not really solve the problem of how to use executemany(). I want to make use of the fact that psycopg3 (as opposed to psycopg2) actually sends the queries in batches when using executemany() to avoid sending the queries one by one.

Comment: I don't think that is possible  From your question: `cursor.executemany(query=query, params_seq=vals)`. The important part being `params_seq=vals`. The parameter values can only be applied to the `%s` or `%(field_name)s` placeholders. There is no way to 'reach' the `{}` placeholders. The query string needs to be built for each table in turn. How many tables are you trying to truncate at a time?